# Does this equation define a differentiable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am solving past calculus exams, and I came across the following question.

Does the equation:
$$
F(x,y,z) = 2\sin(x^2yz) - 3x + 5y^2 - 2e^{yz} = 0
$$
define a differentiable function $z = f(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of $p = (1, 1, 0)$?

At first, I thought this was a natural candidate for the [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), but:
$$
\left.\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}F
\end{matrix}\right|_{(1,1,0)} = 
\begin{matrix}
2x^2y\cos(x^2yz) -2ye^{yz}
\end{matrix}_{(1,1,0)} = 0
$$ 
hence, the theorem doesn't hold in this case.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Fleming, *Functions of several variables*, page 150, if $F(x,y,z(x,y))=0$, then $F_1+F_3 z_1=0$. But in our case $F_3=0$ and $F_1=-3$ at $(1,1,0)$. Hence no differentiable function $z=z(x,y)$ can exists such that $F(x,y,z(x,y))=0$ identically in a neighborhood of $(1,1,0)$.